# Like buttons not working in several articles

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

The facebook like plugin (used as iframe) still not working for the website i work.

I'm aware for the problems that ocurred last week but I don't even have the debugger working for the URLs.

Example:

[simple article](http://extra.globo.com/famosos/zilu-assume-pela-primeira-vez-que-esta-separada-de-zeze-di-camargo-vida-continua-5767649.html)

In the image below you can see where the fb:like button should appear.

[image: fb like button position]

The same URL of the article above at the facebook URL debugger ([link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://extra.globo.com/famosos/zilu-assume-pela-primeira-vez-que-esta-separada-de-zeze-di-camargo-vida-continua-5767649.html)) show no response about the open graph tags - and all the meta tags are ok in my point of view:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://extra.globo.com/famosos/zilu-assume-pela-primeira-vez-que-esta-separada-de-zeze-di-camargo-vida-continua-5767649.html"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Zilu assume pela primeira vez que está separada de Zezé Di Camargo: ‘A vida continua’" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="pt_BR">
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://extra.globo.com/incoming/5767648-1c6-157/w107h60-PROP/zilu-zeze-dicamargo.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Extra Online" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="205680889447721"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100000043813964" />
```

Actually, there is one non-closed meta tag **og_type** but it isn't the real problem ([meta at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp) - section **Differences Between HTML and XHTML** and the page doctype is HTML).

There is a possibility of a problem not in the website but at facebook?

Comment: I just _found_ a article with the button working: [link](http://extra.globo.com/famosos/loura-de-caua-reymond-de-parar-transito-ele-nao-faz-meu-tipo-gosto-da-cor-deixa-caua-para-grazi-5760477.html). But the facebook url debugger still not working: [link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fextra.globo.com%2Ffamosos%2Floura-de-caua-reymond-de-parar-transito-ele-nao-faz-meu-tipo-gosto-da-cor-deixa-caua-para-grazi-5760477.html). The only difference is this article has more likes than the article at the question.

Answer (score 0):

- I would try to put the Like button iFrame outside of the `<div
  id="fb-root">`, it does not belong there. Put it below the `<div
  id="fb-root">` and use a div with another id if you need to wrap it.
- For the debug tool problem I would try to place my og meta data above
  anything else right behind `<meta http-equiv="content-type"
  content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` so that nothing odd happens
  before the Facebook bot scrapes the info it needs.

Comment: for the first point we don't have any XFBML or HTML5 using the **fb-root** div yet - but i'm gonna change that and test it. For the second point we're going to add this meta, thanks!

Comment: and, just for the record, the facebook debugger used to work with our URLs.

Comment: hmmm, well I see the fb-root tag wrapping your like button when I look into the [code](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fextra.globo.com%2Ffamosos%2Fzilu-assume-pela-primeira-vez-que-esta-separada-de-zeze-di-camargo-vida-continua-5767649.html) which the debug tool has scraped for your site.

Comment: apparently the button back to show and work properly. and we didn't nothing.